# Rendering not being called after api request

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am hoping someone can help me, I have been working on a side project for over a month and I can't figure this out.  Here is the code:

```
getNews() {
    var news_items = new Array();
    AsyncStorage.setItem('time', JSON.stringify({'last_cache': moment()}));
    var url = "http://api.podio.com/"
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((responseText) => {
      const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, "text/xml");
      var items = doc.getElementsByTagName('item');
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var appType = new Object();
        appType.title = items[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].data;
        appType.link = items[i].childNodes[3].childNodes[0].data;
        news_items.push(appType);
      }
      var ds = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(news_items);
      console.log("ds: ", ds)
      AsyncStorage.setItem('news_items', JSON.stringify(news_items));
      this.setState({
        'news': ds,
        'loaded': true
      })
      console.log("news: ", this.state.news)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching the feed: ', error);
    });
  }
}

render() {
  console.log("rendering....")
  console.log("loaded? ", this.state.loaded)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.header_item}>
          <Text style={styles.header_text}>{this.state.title}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.header_item}>
          {  !this.state.loaded &&
            <ActivityIndicator />
          }
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <ScrollView ref="scrollView">
          {
            this.state.loaded && <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderNews} ></ListView>
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.getNews();
}

renderNews() {
  console.log("loading....")
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.viewPage(news.link)} underlayColor={"#E8E8E8"} style={styles.button}>
    <View style={styles.news_item}>
    <Text style={styles.news_item_text}>{news.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

As you can see I have quite a few console logs in the code.  Here is what it is telling me:

```
rendering....
loaded?  false
ds:  ListViewDataSource {_dataBlob: Object, _dirtyRows: Array[1],   _dirtySections: Array[1], _cachedRowCount: 142, rowIdentities: Array[1]…}
rendering....
loaded?  true
news:  ListViewDataSource {_dataBlob: Object, _dirtyRows: Array[1], _dirtySections: Array[1], _cachedRowCount: 142, rowIdentities: Array[1]…}
```

Here is the problem.  On the first render it displays "rendering....", but loaded is false, it then sets the ds variable here:

var ds = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(news_items);
console.log("ds: ", ds)

The next time it renders it again displays "rendering...." and now loaded is true.  However, this line in render is never called:

```
this.state.loaded && <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderNews} ></ListView>
```

This line never calls "this.renderNews" and displays its' data.

Additionally, I don't see the console.log for "loading...."

One thing to mention is that this.renderNews is set in the constructor.  In other words: this.renderNews = this.renderNews.bind(this)(edited)

Answer (score 0):

`render` is failed after mounting , means you are calling `setState` wrongly , let the call to be as following:

```
  this.setState({
    'news': ds || [],
    'loaded': true
  })
```

not

```
  this.setState({
    'news': ds,
    'loaded': true
  })
```

by that , you avoid `this.state.news` to not be null ,( assuming that `news` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use conditional rendering on `ListView`. Always render it but initially the datasource is empty. My understanding is that the first rendering builds the component tree. Then subsequent renderings don't actually rebuild the tree, they simply update data on existing components. It's ok to set `visible` props on components and re-rendering will show/hide them properly.

BTW, you don't need the `ScrollView`. `ListView` already has a scroll bar. Nested scrollviews are bad on mobile devices.